# Change links colors based on <spans>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a chat transcript, and inside the chat I want to change the color of links that the `customer` sends to red, while keep the links the `agent` send in blue.

How Can I achieve that in CSS or even better in jQuery. I tried the CSS below but it didn't work

```css
.CustomerPost a{
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<span class="MessagePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/agent.png">
  <span class="Agent">Agent: </span>
    <span class="Message">How may I help you?</span>
  </span>

<span class="MessagePost CustomerPost">
  <img alt="" src="images/user.png">
  <span class="User">Customer: </span>
    <span class="Message">Hi, I need help!<a href="#">www.google.com</a></span>
</span>
```

Comment: no links in this html example

Comment: But there is no a tag in your code. Please share one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sibling selector

```css
.Agent,
.Agent + .Message {
  color: blue
}

.User,
.User + .Message {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<span class="MessagePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/agent.png">
  <span class="Agent">Agent: </span>
    <span class="Message">How may I help you?</span>
  </span>

<span class="MessagePost CustomePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/user.png">
  <span class="User">Customer: </span>
    <span class="Message">Hi, I need help!</span>
</span>
```

If you want a link, than add `a` after the selector.

```css
.Agent + .Message a {
  color: blue
}

.User + .Message a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<span class="MessagePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/agent.png">
  <span class="Agent">Agent: </span>
    <span class="Message">How may I help you? <a href="#">agent</a></span>
  </span>

<span class="MessagePost CustomePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/user.png">
  <span class="User">Customer: </span>
    <span class="Message">Hi, I need help! <a href="#">user</a></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```css
.User .Message a { 
  color: red; 
}

.Agent .Message a { 
  color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working; It is turning the `customer` links to white. Combined with a white background, you don't see it. Just change your CSS to say `color: red;` instead of `color: white;`. The same goes for the links `agent` sends. To select them, use this: `.MessagePost:not(.CustomerPost) a` which will get all `.MessagePost` except the ones that also have the class `.CustomerPost`.

```css
.CustomerPost a {
  color: red;
}
.MessagePost:not(.CustomerPost) a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="MessagePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/agent.png">
  <span class="Agent">Agent: </span>
  <span class="Message"><a href="#">www.google.com</a></span>
</span>
<br>
<span class="MessagePost CustomerPost">
  <img alt="" src="images/user.png">
  <span class="User">Customer: </span>
  <span class="Message"><a href="#">www.google.com</a></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "links" you mean messages, I hope that that's correct.

At present, your HTML uses the `Message` class for messages from both the agent and customer. This makes selecting the correct text a smidgin indirect. However, you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to find the element that is the next sibling of element based on the class by using `+` between the two classes.

```html
 

<style>
.Agent + .Message {
  color:blue;
}
.User + .Message {
  color:red;
}
</style>

<span class="MessagePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/agent.png">
  <span class="Agent">Agent: </span>
    <span class="Message">How may I help you?</span>
  </span>

<span class="MessagePost CustomePost">
  <img alt="" src="images/user.png">
  <span class="User">Customer: </span>
    <span class="Message">Hi, I need help!</span>
</span>
```